# Create uiTabBarController programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I want to create a `UIView` for a `UITabBarController`

Here is my code for the `.h` file :

```
@interface TE : UIViewController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>{
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@end
```

The `viewDidLoad` method:

```
UIViewController *testVC = [[T1 alloc] init];
UIViewController *otherVC = [[T2 alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *topLevelControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[topLevelControllers addObject: testVC];
[topLevelControllers addObject: otherVC];
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate = self;
[tabBarController setViewControllers:topLevelControllers animated:NO];
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
self.view = tabBarController.view;
```

This creates the tab bar controller, but when I click on a tab bar item, I get an error:

> Thread1:Program receive signal: SIGABRT

**Edit**: I solved the problem by downloading and modifying the version of http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/create-uitabbarcontroller/

Comment: on which line exactly do you get the SIGABRT?

Comment: i get it on the main.m in  "return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));"

Comment: but then, the sigabrt would fire at the very start; you could not get to click on anything... how does the AppDelegate class look like?

Comment: the appdelegate class is empty, i didn't add anything, thats the only code i added. and when i click on an item in the tabbarcontroller, i get the sigabrt error

Comment: could you provide the stack trace that you get from the debugger? you can get it by showing the console in Xcode...

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use the same way to add tabbar controller to my app too. But the app keeps crashing when I click on the tabbaritem. Could you possibly tell me how you solved your problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You say above that you don't want to create the tabBarController in the appDelegate. Why not? Where else would you create it? The tabBarController has to be the root view controller and cannot be a child of any other view controller.

Btw, make sure you implement:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger tabIndex = [tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

    if (viewController == [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:tabIndex] ) {
         return YES;
    }

    return NO;

}
```

Comment: i don't wanna create t in the appdelegate because i will add these classes on a project that already have a tabbarcontroller in the delegate

Comment: You're trying to create a tabBarController in an app that already has a tabBarController? You can only have one tabBar. Instead of creating a new additional tabBar you should be accessing the one that is there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Subclass UITabBarController
2. Override the - (void) loadView method and include the following code

   ```
   MyCustomViewControllerOne* ctrl1 = [[[MyCustomViewControllerOne alloc] initWithNibName@"MyViewControllerOne" bundle: nil] autorelease];
   UIViewController* ctrl2 = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
   MyCustomControllerTwo* ctrl3 = [[[UIViewController alloc] initWithObject: myObj] autorelease];

   ctrl1.title = @"First tab";
   ctrl2.title = @"Second tab";
   ctrl3.title = @"Third tab";

   ctrl1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_image1.png"];
   ctrl2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_image2.png"];
   ctrl3.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_image3.png"];

   [self setViewControllers: @[ctrl1, ctrl2, ctrl3]];
   ```

That's pretty much it.

Comment: I had issues overriding the loadView method, but this worked for me when I added it to the viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing

`self.view = tabBarController.view;`

to

`[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];`

See if that helps.

Also try placing this in your `-(void)loadView` method

```
- (void)loadView {

    UIView *mv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, 320.0, 480.0)];

    self.view = mv;

    [mv release];
}
```

The reason you probably are experiencing a black screen is because you haven't initialized your UIView properly.

Comment: when i did replace "self.view = tabbarcontroller;" with [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view]; , the screen remained Black, Weird :(

Comment: Do you see the tabBarController at the bottom?

Comment: Try setting the tabBarController frame like this `tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);`

Comment: Have you implemented the `-(void)loadView` method?

Comment: i always have the blackscreen, and yes i did implement it

Comment: ok i replaced what i had on loadview methode with "UIView *mv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024, 768.0)];
    self.view = mv;" now i see the tabbarcontroller, but when i click on an item i got the SIGABRT

Answer (score 0):

Change `self.view = tabBarController.view;` to
`[self.view  addSubview:tabBarController.view];` And it works correctly

Comment: when i did replace "self.view = tabbarcontroller;" with [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view]; , the screen remained Black, Weird :(

Comment: that's really weird, I created the test project earlier and it did worked. It'd would hard to help without th code at this point. Are you using xibs?

Answer (score 0):

@Mehdi, just make your TE a UITabBarController instead of a UIViewController which then has a TabBarController in it. Makes it all the more easy to manage your TabBarController. To respond to some others who have indicated that you can have only one TabBarController as the window's rootViewController. That is not the case. A UITabBarController can be instantiated in multiple  places where you need a second level menu navigation. Have a TabBar within a TabBar would not make sense, but having a left Navigation Menu and then having a TabBar on each menu item would make sense.