# Display default tabBarView on tabBarItem Click event

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have used `UITabbarController` in my app.One of the tabBarItem is `contactsViewController` which displays list of contacts with `UITableView`.When I click on the tableRow it loads another view.then I click some other `tabBarItem`.again I  click `contactsViewController` it takes me to the view where i left.It does not display default contact view.I have created `UITabbarController` progrmattically.How do i display default tabBarView on `tabBarItem` click?

```
tabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
self.tabbarController.delegate = self;

tabbarView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 431, 320, 49)];

            UIImageView *tabImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 49)];
            [tabImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Taskbar.png"]];
            [tabbarView addSubview:tabImage];

            UIButton *tabItem1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 49)];
            [tabItem1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn_Home.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [tabItem1 setTag:1];
            [tabItem1 addTarget:self action:@selector(tabBarBtnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [tabbarView addSubview:tabItem1];

-(IBAction)tabBarBtnAction:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
//    NSLog(@"tag %d\n",btn.tag);
    [self resetTabBarBtnImage];
    [self resetAllTabBarBtnImage];
    PreviousBtnTag = btn.tag;
    if ([btn tag]==1) {
        tabbarView.hidden = YES;
        [self.tabbarController setSelectedIndex:0];
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn_Home-Over.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else if([btn tag]==2)
    {
        tabbarView.hidden = NO;
        [self.tabbarController setSelectedIndex:1];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Btn_Contacts-Over.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
```

Comment: do you mean to display contactsViewController on the respective tabBar item click?

Comment: yes.I need to display it

Comment: Wny do you feel the need to create tabBar as UIView acting as a tabbar?

Comment: i do not understand what are u asking?

Comment: why cant you use construct a tabBar programmatically the apple way.check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164356/create-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically.

Comment: I created tabBar with tabBarItem progrmatically.didSelectViewController method getting called.When i go to some other tabBarItem and again click contactsViewController i am getting error as UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: if i remove didSelectViewController method it is working fine.is there problem with my tableView

Comment: The error message clearly states whats missing here.You need to check the cellForRowAtIndexPath method to verify this.The didSelectViewController is performing the task correctly

Answer (score 0):

In the `appDelegate` class , initially set the `UItabbarController` `delegate` as `self`

In the implememtation of `appDelegate` i.e .m file

```
//Assuming the first tab has the contactsviewController

-

(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController   {
        if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) {
            UINavigationController *requiredNavigationController = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
            [requiredNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
    }
```

Comment: didSelectViewController method not getting called.

Comment: I added tabBarController through coding.Each tabBarItem is button

Comment: can you post some code showing how the tab bar is programmatically created?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create the "tab bar controller" with the Interface Builder, as it is much easier to implement these kind of things this way. Anyway, if you want to keep trying to create it programmatically, try changing this:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

for this:

```
RootViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Root"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

If this does not work for you, why don't you use Tool Bar Items, in instead of a Tab Bar Controller? It is quite easy to manage events with Tool Bar items, as they are treated like buttons.

Good luck!

Comment: I created tabBar with tabBarItem progrmatically.didSelectViewController method getting called.When i go to some other tabBarItem and again click contactsViewController i am getting error as UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: if i remove didSelectViewController method it is working fine.is there problem with my tableView

Comment: i did not use storyboard.I used only XIB.How do i change ur code for xib?

Comment: If you are using XIB, just use   View Controller *myViewController = [[View Controller alloc] initWithNibName:@"Name" bundle:nil]; and then [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];